# Wrong array order when printing out an array in Spacebars with each

Tags: javascript, arrays, meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars

Got a weird problem here with Meteor, Blaze and Spacebars. Here's my setup: I have a helper that returns an array `[8,8,8,8,8,0,0]`. But when I print it out in my template with `{{#each hours}}{{this}}{{/each}}`, I get the following order: `[8,0,8,8,8,8,0]`.

Why is this happening, am I missing something?

Additionally, when I print out the {{hours}} in the template without the `each` loop, I get the right order.

UPD: For @zim: here's my helper:

```
hours() {
  return [8,8,8,8,8,0,0];
}
```

And the template is pretty much that I described in the post:

```
{{#each hours}}
  {{this}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: Here's my helper:

    hours() {
      return [8,8,8,8,8,0,0];
    }

And the template is pretty much that I described in the post:

    {{#each hours}}
      {{this}}
    {{/each}}

Sorry, can't cope with the markup, will add to the post.

Comment: i am not able to reproduce the behavior you're seeing. i've tried it with an each on "hours" and a "this" in the body, and also with an each on "hour in hours" and an "hour" in the body.

Answer (score 0):

Oddly, it's working fine today. I have no idea what it was, but will get back to this topic whenever I experience this problem again.